# groupby, apply, and set not behaving as expected... is this a bug?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

To see the issue, consider the following dataframe

```
In [66]: dat = pandas.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'],
                        columns=['letters'])

In [67]: dat['numbers'] = pandas.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])

In [68]: dat['names'] = pandas.Series(['jim','jan','jerry','george'
                        ,'mary','mary','sue','sue'])

In [69]: dat
Out[69]:
  letters  numbers   names
0       a        1     jim
1       b        2     jan
2       c        3   jerry
3       d        4  george
4       e        5    mary
5       f        6    mary
6       g        7     sue
7       h        8     sue
```

Group by names

```
In [78]: dat = dat.groupby(['names'])[['letters']]
```

Now my attempt to concat letters produces a funny result:

```
In [80]: dat.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(set(x)))
Out[80]:
names
george    letters|numbers|names
jan       letters|numbers|names
jerry     letters|numbers|names
jim       letters|numbers|names
mary      letters|numbers|names
sue       letters|numbers|names
dtype: object
```

The following hack seems to work but why do I need to select 'letters' again, and why does the output above look as it does?

```
In [84]: dat.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(set(x['letters'])))
Out[84]:
names
george      d
jan         b
jerry       c
jim         a
mary      e|f
sue       h|g
dtype: object
```

Could this be a bug?

**INSTALLED VERSIONS**

commit: None
python: 2.7.5.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 13.1.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: en_US.UTF-8

pandas: 0.13.1
Cython: 0.20.1
numpy: 1.6.2
scipy: 0.11.0
statsmodels: 0.5.0
IPython: 2.0.0
sphinx: 1.2.2
patsy: 0.2.1
scikits.timeseries: None
dateutil: 1.5
pytz: 2012d
bottleneck: None
tables: None
numexpr: None
matplotlib: 1.1.1
openpyxl: None
xlrd: None
xlwt: None
xlsxwriter: None
sqlalchemy: None
lxml: 3.3.5
bs4: 4.3.2
html5lib: None
bq: None
apiclient: None

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may seem a bit strange, but as you see set of a DataFrame is it's columns:

```
In [11]: dat
Out[11]:
  letters  numbers   names
0       a        1     jim
1       b        2     jan
2       c        3   jerry
3       d        4  george
4       e        5    mary
5       f        6    mary
6       g        7     sue
7       h        8     sue

[8 rows x 3 columns]

In [12]: set(dat)
Out[12]: {'letters', 'names', 'numbers'}
```

That's due to the way you iterate through a DataFrame (by the columns):

```
In [13]: for i in dat: print(i)
letters
numbers
names
```

This would work with the SeriesGroupBy (iterating through a Series iterates through its elements):

```
In [21]: g = dat.groupby(['names'])['letters']

In [22]: g.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(set(x)))
Out[22]:
names
george      d
jan         b
jerry       c
jim         a
mary      e|f
sue       h|g
dtype: object
```

Note: You don't need the set or, indeed, the lambda:

```
In [23]: g.apply('|'.join)
Out[23]:
names
george      d
jan         b
jerry       c
jim         a
mary      e|f
sue       g|h
dtype: object
```

Comment: In conclusion, not a bug :)

Comment: [@Andy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1240268/andy-hayden), why does `dat.groupby(['names'])[['letters']]` pass all the columns through to apply (letters, numbers, names)? Why not just the 'letters' column as a dataframe instead of a series? Is it ignoring `[['letters']]` (syntatic sugar that's not allowed)?

Comment: @KarlD. Ah ha, that part **is** in fact a bug which should be fixed in 0.14rc ! Can't recall the # on github, was part of https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5264.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the issue on github.  In response to your note... the `set()` function is a remnant from my application where I am looking to extract unique elements from a letters-like column.